# App with already filled database in the apk

Tags: java, android

i want to create an app that uses a database already completed and filled with name and numbers, in detail this app only reads the database and filter some data, for example shows me only "male" contacts in the database. I want to use that app on different phones, so the problem is to incorporate the database in the apk..what kind of database i can use?

Comment: hint: You could either store your data in json or sqlite script in your assets folder. When application is running for the first time you can read the file and populate database.

Comment: Thank you Sharj, i made like you said and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the database on a web server and get the data at first run of your app to store it locally. You can find a good tutorial for retrieving data from server at http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/.

Answer (score 0):

Document Orientated Database - A document-oriented database or document store is a computer program designed for storing, retrieving, and managing document-oriented information, also known as semi-structured data.

Comment: At least link to the Wikipedia page you lifted every word of that text from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database